# Is it possible to ensure typesafety (including different POJO versions) when (de-)serialising java-POJOs with the boon ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, json, serialization

I am searching for a comfortable way to serialize / deserialize my java Pojos to JSON and came across Boon. I created a simple test code like this:

```
ObjectMapper boonMapper = JsonFactory.create();
File file = temporaryFolder.newFile();
boonMapper.writeValue(file, myPojoList);
// test if serialized as desired
List<MyPojo> pojoList = boonMapper.readValue(file, ArrayList.class, MyPojo.class);
// test if deserialized as desired
```

It works fast and all values of my pojos are restored to my list. 
If i delete some values from the JSON File boon simply sets those values in my pojo to null or 0, which is ok. BUT if i add some values to the JSON file, which have no representive field in the pojo class, boon ignores those values, which of course results in loss of information. Jackson for example throws an error in those cases, which would be the desired behavior. I did not find any ways to configure boon to handle those cases differently, for example with annotations, like it is possible in Jackson.
Performance is crucial for this serialization, so i am looking for faster alternatives to Jackson. But i like to have a JSON representation in serialized form and not a binary one. Thats why i started working with boon in the first place.
So in summary: Is there a way to configure boon like Jackson? If not, are there alternatives to boon?
Any suggestions or ideas are welcome, thank you

Comment: Hi, did you got an answer ?

Comment: i ended up using the jackson object mapper